# DAX: Accessing values of parents? (using junction table)

Tags: powerbi, dax

Imagine this situation:

[image: Relationship diagram]

[image: stores table]
[image: relationship table]

And you want to add a calculated column to the `stores` table.

This `Calculated` column would find all the parents the child has and combine (sum or average) all its `some_value`'s.

I was trying to do it in a way like this

```
Calculated =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( stores[some_value] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( stores ),
        'stores'[store_child_and_parent] = VALUES ( store_relationship[store_parent] )
    )
)
```

but I feel lost.

Comment: can you post your desired result?

Comment: @StelioK If we sum as an example, then it would be store 4 that is equal to 111 some_value, and store 5 to 666 (because 111+222+333).

Comment: Ouch.. I hate that number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after spending 2-3 days I've managed to crack it!
Here's the beautiful piece of code:

```
measure = CALCULATE(
    SUM(
        'stores'[some_value]
    ),
    FILTER(
        ALL('stores'),
        'stores'[store_child_and_parent] in VALUES('store_relationship'[store_parent])
    )
)
```

And another very interesting one - if, say, `some_value` was a measure that was doing `SUM()` and, say, you wanted to get an average of those sums, you can group these like so:

```
measure = CALCULATE(
    AVERAGEX(
        'stores',
        'stores'[some_value]
    ),
    FILTER(
        ALL('stores'),
        'stores'[store_child_and_parent] in VALUES('store_relationship'[store_parent])
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple ways to achieve this:

```
Calculated = 
    VAR StoreList = FILTER(store_relationship,
                        store_relationship[store_child] = EARLIER(stores[store_child_and_parent]))
    RETURN CALCULATE(
               SUMX(StoreList, RELATED(stores[some_value])),
               USERELATIONSHIP(stores[store_child_and_parent], store_relationship[store_parent]))
```

You could also use a lookup:

```
Calculated = 
    VAR StoreList = FILTER(store_relationship,
                        store_relationship[store_child] = EARLIER(stores[store_child_and_parent]))
    RETURN SUMX(StoreList,
               LOOKUPVALUE(stores[some_value],
                   stores[store_child_and_parent], store_relationship[store_parent]))
```

Comment: Gives me a "EARLIER/EARLIEST refers to an earlier row context which doesn't exist." error. :(

Comment: The suggestions I gave were for a calculated column like your question asked for. It appears that you actually wanted a measure instead.

Comment: Huh, but I did ask for a measure in my question! @Alexis Olson has edited my post and changed measure to calculated for some reason. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Nevermind, I found the answer.

Comment: I'm very sorry. That's my fault indeed. You originally said "measure column" and I incorrectly assumed that meant a calculated column since you specified a column rather than just a measure. I was attempting to clarify, but I got it the wrong way.